# How to take last element with a specific value in a list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a Document object which has a "type" attribute. I need to loop a list of Document and for each document.type == "OTHER" I have to take the last element in the list which was a "MIC" document.type. How can I do this easily?

Comment: You should include in your question your attempts and what didn't work for you. And please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Not enough information - add the document and the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reversed the list and looped through it
If the type of the new element if not one of certain types, it is seen as other and breaks the loop as it was originally the last of this type

```
types = [float, str]

texts = ['hello', 3, 2.5, 'world', 7, 8, 1.4]

texts = texts[::-1]

for i in texts:
    ty = type(i)
    if ty in types:
        pass
    else:
        other = ty
        print(i)
        break
```